# Draw line with shadow

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin

Right now i draw line without shadow:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val dividerStart = parent.paddingStart
        val dividerEnd = parent.width - parent.paddingEnd
        val endIndex = parent.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
        for (index in 0 until endIndex) {
            val currentChild = parent.getChildAt(index)
            if (needDrawBottomDelimiter(parent, currentChild)) {
                val topOfCurrentView = currentChild.top
                val startX = dividerStart.toFloat()
                val topY = topOfCurrentView.toFloat() - rectHeight
                val endX = dividerEnd.toFloat()
                val bottomY = topOfCurrentView.toFloat()
                canvas.drawRect(startX, topY, endX, bottomY, spacePaint)
                canvas.drawLine(startX, bottomY, endX, bottomY, dividerPaint)
            }
        }
    }
```

I know what can help me shader, but doesn't know how i can use it here.

Let me know how to use **shader** here.

Comment: May be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099465/creating-a-shadow-around-a-canvas-drawn-shape

Comment: @deepakkumar thx, this is solved my problem ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a shadow around a canvas drawn shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099465/creating-a-shadow-around-a-canvas-drawn-shape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099465/creating-a-shadow-around-a-canvas-drawn-shape) `deepak kumar`

```
dividerPaint.setShadowLayer(12F, 0F, 0F, Color.YELLOW)
setLayerType(parent, LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, dividerPaint)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you can do:

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack" />
```

Comment: I need to set programmatically
not for the whole view

Answer (score 0):

You just try the below method:

```
 Paint paint;

 paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 paint.setShadowLayer(12, 0, 0, Color.YELLOW);

 // Important for certain APIs 
 setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {   
        canvas.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100, paint);
    }
```